# Data from the server is not assigned to a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting data from a server. I receive data and with the help of DrinkModel.fromJson I receive it. The data is assigned to the value and timestamp variables. But the `addDrinkWater` variable is set to `null`. Why such an error? If the data comes to me and they are assigned inside the DrinkModel.

**settings_model**

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class SettingsModel extends HiveObject {

  @HiveField(13)
  DrinkModel? addDrinkWater;

  SettingsModel({
    this.addDrinkWater,
  });

  SettingsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    addDrinkWater = AddDrinkModel.fromJson(json['_counter']);
  }
```

**drink_model**

```
@HiveType(typeId: 48)
class AddDrinkModel extends HiveObject {
  AddDrinkModel({
    required this.value,
    required this.timestamp,
  });

  @HiveField(0, defaultValue: 0)
  late int value;

  @HiveField(1, defaultValue: 1)
  late int timestamp;

  AddDrinkModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    value = json['value'] ?? 0;
    timestamp = DateTime.parse(DateTime.parse(
                json['timestamp'] ?? DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch)
            .toIso8601String())
        .millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['value'] = value;
    data['timestamp'] =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp).toString();
    return data;
  }
}
```

**json**

```
"settings": {
            "_counter": {
                "value": 0,
                "timestamp": "2023-06-06T13:27:36.627Z"
            },
```

the data inside the AddDrinkModel is saved

[image]

data in the addDrinkWater variable is not saved

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  AddDrinkModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
value = json['value'] ?? 0;
timestamp = DateTime.parse(DateTime.parse(
            json['timestamp'] ?? DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch)
        .toIso8601String())
    .millisecondsSinceEpoch;
return AddDrinkModel(value, timestamp);
```

}

Aren't you missing a return? (not used to work with hive, unless it changes this, seems the return is missing to me)